# Electronegativity in superconducters

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, superconductivity, physical-chemistry

What role if any does electronegativity have in superconductors.

Most of the elements used in superconductors on the periodic table are at the low end of electronegativity and I was wondering if there is any correlation?